# Meaning of EnableNodeOUs in crypto-config.yaml?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Just wondering what the flag EnableNodeOUs means in crypto-config.yaml?

eg:

```
 PeerOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org1
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Org1
    Domain: org1.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Fabric v1.1, we added the ability to classify identities as either a "client" or a "peer".  This allows you to create policies such as `Org.peer` and `Org.client` in addition to the existing `Org.member` and `Org.admin`.  If you enable this is cryptogen, it will generate MSPs which use this feature.

See http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/msp.html#identity-classification

and then

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/endorsement-policies.html#specifying-endorsement-policies-for-a-chaincode

for how to use the roles in endorsement policies

Comment: can you please tell how to assign roles during certificate generation for peers.

Comment: it might be best to create a new question with more detail on exactly what you want to do; i.e. are you using cryptogen, etc

Comment: now i am able to assign role to peer using cryptogen based on  your answers from other posts. but i am stuck in endorsement policy failure, for which i have created stack overflow question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928135/peer-endorsement-policy-not-working-hyperledger-fabric). please help me in resolving this issue. Thanks.