# peer endorsement policy not working hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I am trying to enforce simple endorsement policy for 2 org network. Here is my `crypto-config.yaml`

```
OrdererOrgs:
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: example.com
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
PeerOrgs:
  - Name: Org1
    Domain: org1.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    # CA:
    #   OrganizationalUnit: peer
    Template:
      Count: 1
    Users:
      Count: 1
  - Name: Org2
    Domain: org2.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    # CA:
    #   OrganizationalUnit: peer
    Template:
      Count: 1
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

And i can see OU as peer in both peers.

```
peer0.org2.example.com  
Identity: peer0.org2.example.com  
Verified by: ca.org2.example.com  
Expires: Saturday 23 December 2028
```

Subject Name

```
C (Country):    US  
ST (State): California  
L (Locality):   San Francisco  
OU (Organizational Unit):   peer  
CN (Common Name):   peer0.org2.example.com
```

endorsement policy for member check works

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n chaincode -l node -v v0 -c '{"args":["init"]}' -P "AND('Org1MSP.member', 'Org2MSP.member')"
```

but endorsement policy for peer check not working

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n chaincode -l node -v v0 -c '{"args":["init"]}' -P "AND('Org1MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.peer')"
```

When i invoke any function.

`Transaction failed to be committed to the ledger due to ::ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE`

even `"OR('Org1MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.peer')"` not working

Comment: How did you create `mychannel`?

Comment: through cli container,  
docker exec cli peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/config/channel.tx

Comment: And did you use `configtxgen` after using `cryptogen` with NodeOUs enabled?

Comment: yes,  in generate.sh i have following commands.  
cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml ||    
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./config/genesis.block   || 
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./config/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME  ||
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./config/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org1MSP   ||
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./config/Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org2MSP

Comment: Had the same issue. Adding EnableNodeOUs in my crypto-config.yaml fixed it for me. Thanks @GariSingh!

Answer (score 0):

```
PeerOrgs:
  - Name: Org1
    Domain: org1.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    # CA:
    #   OrganizationalUnit: peer
    Template:
      Count: 1
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

.........   TEMPLATE COUNT s/b changed to 2 as there are now 2 Orgs

Comment: Nope,the Template count refers to the number of peers here in the Organization.It should be updated to "2" if there are 2 peers under Org1 which is not clearly specified here in the question.